# SMTP MAIL FROM: being received as DATA: From?

Tags: email, smtp

I'm writing a recreational email spoofing app with several safeguards to make the app useless to spammers and other malicious people. One of these safeguards is that the app requires the user to send emails from the user's own SMTP account. The app is supposed to use this "login@smtp.example.com" for the MAIL FROM command. The From: field visible to the user is supposed to be spoofedAddress@example.com. I'm using Apache Commons Net SMTP. Here are relevant code fragments.

```
AuthenticatingSMTPClient client = new AuthenticatingSMTPClient();
....
client.auth(AuthenticatingSMTPClient.AUTH_METHOD.LOGIN, "login@smtp.example.com", "password");
....
client.setSender("login@smtp.example.com");
....
SimpleSMTPHeader header = new SimpleSMTPHeader("spoofedAddress@example.com", "Addressee@example.com", "Subject");
....
```

When the email arrives in my inbox, it displays "login@smtp.example.com" in the both the From: field and the envelope. "spoofedAddress@example.com" is nowhere to be seen. I used `Log.e("SendMail", header.toString());` to show me the header produced by my app and it was correct. It appears that my email client is ignoring my header in favour of the envelope.

---

Solution

My SMTP server was intrusively editing the From: field. When I told my app to connect to a different SMTP server, "spoofedAddress@example.com" appeared in the received email's From: field.

Comment: More likely the server has an anti-spoofing override.

Comment: Can your email client display the MIME source? What's in the "From:" field? If it's spoofedAddress@example.com and the field is correctly formatted, then the client likely displays the "Sender" field, added somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Skynet Please refrain from making gratuitous edits. "Fixing" US English is obnoxious and intrusive, and your other changes were even more minor.

Comment: @PeterK The "From:" field's contents is "login@smtp.example.com" in the MIME source displayed by my email client. "spoofedAddress@example.com" appears nowhere in the source. It's as if the header in the DATA portion of email is being altered.

Comment: @tripleee I used a "Contact Us" form on a website I manage to spoof an email and my email client displayed the spoofed address correctly. The website uses different POP3 and SMTP servers than my app. Since I can't find a code error to explain what is happening, a server is probably involved. Perhaps I should move my question to a server-oriented board?

Comment: @HalfGenius: I'd use WireShark or other packet capture software to confirm what MIME data is sent to the server. If it checks out, at least we know for sure it's the server. In any case, the kind of "spoofing" you do is perfectly legal and frequently employed by email newsletters, mailing lists, etc., so the server should not interfere.